# How can I schedule awaitables for sequential execution without awaiting?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, python-3.6, python-asyncio

Suppose, I have a few async functions, `f1`, `f2` and `f3`. I want to execute these functions in a sequential order. The easiest way to do this would be to await on them:

```
async def foo():
    await f1()
    # Do something else
    await f2()
    # Do something else
    await f3()
    # Do something else
```

However, I don't care about the results of these async functions, and I would like to continue with the execution of the rest of the function after scheduling the async functions.

From the [asyncio tasks documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) it seems that `asyncio.ensure_future()` can help me with this. I used the following code to test this out, and the synchronous parts of `foo()` as per my expectations. However, `bar()` never executes past  `asyncio.sleep()`

```
import asyncio

async def bar(name):
    print(f'Sleep {name}')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print(f'Wakeup {name}')

async def foo():
    print('Enter foo')

    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        asyncio.ensure_future(bar(i))
        print(f'Scheduled bar({i}) for execution')

    print('Exit foo')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(foo())
```

The output for the above code:

```
Enter foo
Scheduled bar(1) for execution
Scheduled bar(2) for execution
Scheduled bar(3) for execution
Exit foo
Sleep 1
Sleep 2
Sleep 3
```

So, what is the proper method to do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a few async functions, `f1`, `f2` and `f3`. I want to execute these functions in a sequential order. [...] I would like to continue with the execution of the rest of the function after scheduling the async functions.

The straightforward way to do this is by using a helper function and letting it run it in the background:

```
async def foo():
    async def run_fs():
        await f1()
        await f2()
        await f3()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(run_fs())
    # proceed with stuff that foo needs to do
    ...
```

`create_task` submits a coroutine to the event loop. You can also use `ensure_future` for that, but `create_task` is [preferred](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-268709555) when spawning a coroutine.

The code in the question has two issues: first, the functions are not run sequentially, but in parallel. This is fixed as shown above, by running a single async function in the background that awaits the three in order. The second problem is that in asyncio `run_until_complete(foo())` only waits for `foo()` to finish, not also for the tasks spawned by `foo` (though there are asyncio [alternatives](https://github.com/python-trio/trio) that [address](https://vorpus.org/blog/notes-on-structured-concurrency-or-go-statement-considered-harmful/#nurseries-a-structured-replacement-for-go-statements) this). If you want `run_until_complete(foo())` to wait for `run_fs` to finish, `foo` has to await it itself.

Fortunately, that is trivial to implement - just add another `await` at the end of `foo()`, awaiting the task created for `run_fs` earlier. If the task is already done by that point, the `await` will exit immediately, otherwise it will wait.

```
async def foo():
    async def run_fs():
        await f1()
        await f2()
        await f3()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    f_task = loop.create_task(run_fs())
    # proceed with stuff that foo needs to do
    ...
    # finally, ensure that the fs have finished by the time we return
    await f_task
```