# How to schedule awaitables for sequential execution without awaiting, without prior knowing the number of awaitables?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

What I would like to do is essentially described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023432/how-can-i-schedule-awaitables-for-sequential-execution-without-awaiting).

However, I do not know how many awaitables I will execute.

If I were to use threading my code would be like this:

```py
def foo():
   # some blocking call 

result_list = []
threads = []
for i in events:  # events is a list different every time
     newthread = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=())          
     threads.append(newthread)
     newthread.start()
print(result_list)
```

How can I turn this into async code?

I suppose `foo()` should look like this:

```py
async def foo():
   global result_list
   result = await blocking_call()
   result_list.append(result)
```

I have tried to create tasks in another thread, but this approach doesn't seem to function properly.

**EDIT**

I would like to do something like this:

```py
def foo():
   # some blocking call 

result_list = []
threads = []
for i in events:  # events is a list different every time
     time.sleep(i)
     newthread = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=())          
     threads.append(newthread)
     newthread.start()
print(result_list)
```

Comment: See `asyncio.gather`.

Comment: It seems to me that asyncio.gather first gathers all tasks and sends them all together to execute. What I want is to execute tasks sequentially but "bypass" the await part

Comment: From your code it seems like you do, in fact, know how many awaitables you will have - it's `len(events)`.  Please explain why you want to use asyncio when the purpose of the code is apparently to make a blocking call.  That's the use case for which asyncio is almost certainly the wrong tool.

Comment: It makes no sense to say you want the tasks to execute sequentially without awaiting, since 'await` is the mechanism that allows Tasks to execute in sequence.  The main purpose of asyncio is to execute Tasks in parallel; if you don't want that, don't use asyncio.

Comment: You cannot "bypass" the `await` when dealing with coroutines. At some point, one way or another, you need to actually **schedule** them for execution. And if you want one coroutine to execute **strictly after** another, you **must** `await` the first before scheduling the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other question you linked has the answer. The only thing you need to do differently, if you don't know the number of coroutines ahead of time, is put the calls and `await`s of your coroutines in a loop.

But the helper task based approach is still the simplest solution in my opinion.

Here is a very simple demo:

```py
from asyncio import create_task, run, sleep
from collections.abc import Iterable


async def foo(x: float) -> None:
    print(f"Executing foo({x=})")
    await sleep(x)
    print(f"Finished foo({x=})")


async def foo_sequentially(xs: Iterable[float]) -> None:
    for x in xs:
        await foo(x)


async def main() -> None:
    foo_inputs = [0.25, 0.5, 1., 1.5]
    foo_seq_task = create_task(foo_sequentially(foo_inputs))
    ...  # do other stuff, while `foo_seq_task` is scheduled/executes
    print("  Doing other stuff...")
    await sleep(1)
    print("  Doing more stuff...")
    await sleep(1)
    print("  Done with other stuff!")
    await foo_seq_task


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

Output:

```
  Doing other stuff...
Executing foo(x=0.25)
Finished foo(x=0.25)
Executing foo(x=0.5)
Finished foo(x=0.5)
Executing foo(x=1.0)
  Doing more stuff...
Finished foo(x=1.0)
Executing foo(x=1.5)
  Done with other stuff!
Finished foo(x=1.5)
```

As you can see the `foo` coroutines all executed **sequentially** with respect to one another, and viewed as a whole (wrapped in `foo_sequentially`) they executed **concurrently** to the rest of the things done by `main`.

That is because *by definition* an `await` statement will **block** the **encompassing** coroutine (in this case `foo_sequentially`), until the awaitable in that statement returns (in this case one of the `foo` coroutines); but the `await` statement will also **yield** control to the event loop allowing it to resume execution of some **other** coroutine (in this case `main`).